# Returning values from a function using a switch statement to call the fnctions

Tags: c

My question is i have been asked to write a menu driven program that will ask the user to 1. enter a 4 digit code 2. Encrypt the code and verify against a set 4 digit code. 3. Exit the program. The program should loop back to the start menu after the user is done with their selected option apart from when they choose to exit. i.e the user will enter their code and return to the menu before encrypting and verifying the code entered against a set 4 digit code.
My code below does not loop back to the menu nor does it run correctly when i choose option 1 it asks me to enter the 4 digit code twice. I have tried tiredlessy to fix this but to no avail. Any help you can give me would be great.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #define CODE 4

    //prototypes
    int enter_code (int* code_arr);
    int encrypt_code (int* pass_code, int* user_code);

    int main(void)
    {
        //declare variables
        int password[CODE] = {0}; 
        int passOK[CODE] = {4,5,2,3};
        int option;
        int exit1;
        int code;

        //do while loop
        do
        {   

            //print the menu on screen
            printf("\t \t \t  \t Pearse Security \n \n");
            printf("\t \t \t1 - Enter the access code\n");
            printf("\t \t \t2 - Enter the encrypt code and verify\n");
            printf("\t \t \t3 - Exit the program \n");

            //scan for user input
            scanf("%d",& option);

            switch(option)
            {
                case 1:
                {
                    code =enter_code(password);

                    break;
                }

                case 2:
                {
                    if (encrypt_code(passOK, password))
                    printf("You unlocked the vault\n");

                    break;

                }

                case 3:
                {
                    // prompt user to a key to exit
                    printf("\n You choose to exit the program.\n Press a key to exit\n "); 
                    getchar();
                    exit(0);

                    break;

                } 

                default:
                {
                    printf("You must enter a number between 1-5\n");
                }

          } // end switch()

      if (!enter_code(password))
       {
            printf ("Bad password entry\n");
       }

      else 
      {
           if (encrypt_code(passOK, password))
           {
                printf("You unlocked the vault\n");
           }

     else
            printf("You don't know the passcode\n");
      }

    return 0;

    }//end do

    while(exit1!=4 & exit1 <5);

    }//end main()


    //enter code function()
    int enter_code (int* code_arr)
    {
        //declare variables for enter_code()
        int i;

        //prompt user to enter the 4 digit code
        printf("Enter your 4 digit code\n");

        for(i=0;i<CODE;i++)
        {
            if (scanf("%d", &code_arr[i]) != 1)
        {
            return 0;
        }//end if()

        }//end for()
          return 1;
    }//end enter_code()

    //encrypt code and verify function

    int encrypt_code (int* pass_code, int* user_code)
    {
        //variables for encrypt_code()
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<CODE;i++)
    {
        if (pass_code[i] != user_code[i])
        {
            return 0;
        }//end if()

    }//end for()

    return 1;

}//end encrypt_code()


The output of this program is 
Enter 4 digits
4
5
2
3
Enter 4 digits
4
5
2
3
```

You have unlocked the vault
And the program ends
Why does it ask me to enter the code twice and why does it not loop back to the menu.

Comment: @Weather Vane I don't know if this makes it any clearer

Comment: Why don't you use `while(condition){...}` ?

Comment: you have a `return 0` inside your do while loop

Comment: I have tried it outside the while loop it still does not work.

Comment: @PMCL88 please format your code better so I can read it and try to help you.

Comment: Having `return 0` inside will definitely not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received two compiler warnings about this line

```
while(exit1!=4 & exit1 <5);
```

Firstly it should be

```
while(exit1!=4 && exit1 <5);
```

It is also *undefined behaviour* since `exit1` has never been assigned a value.

I suggest you replace the line with

```
while(1);
```

since `case 3:` contains an `exit()`.

Next, you say that `enter_code()` is being called twice. The reason is because it is being called twice: once within `case 1:` and again outside the `switch()` code block.

Here is the amended `main()` in which I deleted the surplus stuff below the `switch()` block and added a failure message to `case 2:`

```
int main(void)
{
    int password[CODE] = {0}; 
    int passOK[CODE] = {4,5,2,3};
    int option;
    int code;

    do
    {   
        printf("\t \t \t  \t Pearse Security \n \n");
        printf("\t \t \t1 - Enter the access code\n");
        printf("\t \t \t2 - Enter the encrypt code and verify\n");
        printf("\t \t \t3 - Exit the program \n");
        scanf("%d",& option);
        switch(option)
        {
            case 1: {
                code =enter_code(password);
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                if (encrypt_code(passOK, password))
                    printf("You unlocked the vault\n");
                else
                    printf("You don't know the passcode\n");
                break;
            }
            case 3:{
                // prompt user to a key to exit
                printf("\n You choose to exit the program.\n Press a key to exit\n "); 
                getchar();
                exit(0);
                break;
            } 
            default: {
                printf("You must enter a number between 1-5\n");
            }
        }
    } while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi i have edited the while loop and assigned it a value and it works a complete oversight on my behalf. I realise i am calling it twice, but i have another issue how do i call it from the switch statment and return the code that is entered.  This is where my real issue is i believe.

Comment: @PMCL88 it *does* get entered at `case 1:` but I have amended my answer anyway to add a revised `main()`.

Comment: Yes the code gets entered at case 1 and verified in case 2.  Which you have shown in the above code. Thanks so much for that Weather Vane, you have helped me more than you probably should of for which i am extremely grateful.